# How can I get a file's size in C++?

Tags: c++, filesize

Let's create a complementary question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c).
What is the most common way to get the file size in C++?
Before answering, make sure it is portable (may be executed on Unix, Mac and Windows),
reliable, easy to understand and without library dependencies (no boost or qt, but for instance glib is ok since it is portable library).

Comment: May dupicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409504

Comment: Why no boost but allow glib? Boost is also portable.

Comment: @mmutz: "Portable" has a different meaning than "standard".  For example, Boost is more portable than standard C++ because it has workarounds for non-compliancies of compilers (including older versions).  Fstat is portable in the strictest sense.

Comment: @Thomas: There can be no "portable" without a standard. That standard may be in the form of a written document (like POSIX, or C++) and you hope that all implementations are true to it, or it may be by way of a common implementation that has been ported to many platforms (most libraries, incl. Boost). `fstat()` is standardized in POSIX, but Windows chose to deviate from that standard by calling the funciton `_fstat()`. `fstat()` is _not_ portable, because you need an `#ifdef _WIN32` to use it.

Comment: Lots of boost functions are portable but needs to compile explicitly.

Comment: //win32 file details
ULONGLONG GetFileSizeAtt(const wchar_t *wFile)
{
 WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fileInfo;
 ULONGLONG FileSize = 0ULL;
 //https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN
 //https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/win32/api/fileapi/ns-fileapi-win32_file_attribute_data?redirectedfrom=MSDN
 if (GetFileAttributesEx(wFile, GetFileExInfoStandard, &fileInfo))
 {
  ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
  ul.HighPart = fileInfo.nFileSizeHigh;
  ul.LowPart = fileInfo.nFileSizeLow;
  FileSize = ul.QuadPart;
 }
 return FileSize;
}

Answer (score 171, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream::pos_type filesize(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    return in.tellg(); 
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ for more information on files in C++.

edit: this answer is not correct since tellg() does not necessarily return the right value. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22986486/1835769

Comment: Why do you need `std::ifstream::in ` here? There is no input to the stream at all.

Comment: Or just get it from the file system with stat where the size is already maintained.  No need to even open the file.

Comment: Based on @jterm suggestion, opening the stream would be `std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);` Just to ease everybody's life ;)

Comment: Don't you need to close the file?

Comment: @WillingGood the file will be closed after returning of the function.

Comment: How to get the file size from tellg()???

Comment: Just to let you know, this nice solution does not work in VS 2013 (up to Update5) in 64 bit for large files >4GB due to a bug in VC++ [1683089](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1683089). So better use seekg(0, end); and then tellg(); as a workaround until it's fixed.

Comment: What will be the time complexity of this function? Will it be `O(1)` or `O(n)`, `n` being the size of file in bytes?

Comment: This answer to a question on SO says that [tellg does not report the size of the file, nor the offset from the beginning in bytes.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22986486/1835769)

Comment: is there a file size limitation with this approach?  what's the size of the return value?

Comment: in addition to the 64 bit problem, this opens the file, which can have unwelcome side effects.   better to use POSIX  stat() (below)

Comment: As mentioned above I don't think tellg() is guaranteed to return size, although it always has for me on linux systems I've done it on (so use at your own risk).

Comment: Is it less efficient than `C` `stat()`?

Comment: this is missleading answer, since there is no way to convert pos_type to int/long

Comment: This does not work for files provided by virtual filesystem driver s3fs (i.e. Amazon S3 files mounted using s3fs). `tellg()` returns a negative number

Answer (score 121):

Using the C++ filesystem library:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::filesystem::path p{argv[1]};

  std::cout << "The size of " << p.u8string() << " is " <<
      std::filesystem::file_size(p) << " bytes.\n";
}
```

Comment: worth noting that `filesystem` is ISO C++ as of C++17

Comment: so is that faster than tellg?

Comment: Do we really need to canonicalize the filename first?!

Comment: @MohamadElnaqeeb just benchmarked this on g++8; it is slightly faster and it is correct, unlike seekg and tellg.

Comment: Always read StackOverflow pages from the bottom up!

Answer (score 116):

While not necessarily the most popular method, I've heard that the ftell, fseek method may not always give accurate results in some circumstances.  Specifically, if an already opened file is used and the size needs to be worked out on that and it happens to be opened as a text file, then it's going to give out wrong answers.

The following methods should always work as stat is part of the c runtime library on Windows, Mac and Linux.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

long GetFileSize(std::string filename)
{
    struct stat stat_buf;
    int rc = stat(filename.c_str(), &stat_buf);
    return rc == 0 ? stat_buf.st_size : -1;
}

or 

long FdGetFileSize(int fd)
{
    struct stat stat_buf;
    int rc = fstat(fd, &stat_buf);
    return rc == 0 ? stat_buf.st_size : -1;
}
```

If you need this for very large files (>2GB) you may want to look at calling `stat64` and `fstat64` if available.

Comment: The above code is portable to both C & C++

Comment: +1 For the mention of opening the stream in binary mode. That fixed an issue I was having using the fseek()+ftell() size with read().

Comment: I needed to add #include <sys/stat.h> and GetFileSize(...) works for me.

Comment: be aware of the fact that long is 4 byte in Visual Studio, so you have to use f.e. long long to get correct file size for big files on Windows

Comment: this approach works for files <2GBs

Answer (score 30):

It is also possible to find that out using the fopen(),fseek() and ftell() function.

```
int get_file_size(std::string filename) // path to file
{
    FILE *p_file = NULL;
    p_file = fopen(filename.c_str(),"rb");
    fseek(p_file,0,SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(p_file);
    fclose(p_file);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: You do not need `<fstream>` and `<iostream>`, you do need `<string>` and you need error checking. (`fseek` segfaults when using a NULL file, ftell returns -1 on error)

Comment: Initializing p_file and overwriting it in the next line is pointless and and makes many lints complain about "unused assignment".

Comment: Should you use `long` for the return type?

Comment: " Library implementations are allowed to not meaningfully support SEEK_END (therefore, code using it has no real standard portability)"

Comment: Related link: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek()+and+ftell()+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file

Comment: Do you need a null check?  What happens if p_file is NULL?

Comment: This answer is missleading and should be downvoted imho:https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("mainfinal.c" , "r");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(f);
    printf("%ld\n", len);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Extra points for not getting completely sucked into the idea that it has to be done with modern constructs.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ you can use following function, it will return the size of you file in bytes.

```
#include <fstream>

int fileSize(const char *add){
    ifstream mySource;
    mySource.open(add, ios_base::binary);
    mySource.seekg(0,ios_base::end);
    int size = mySource.tellg();
    mySource.close();
    return size;
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work, you can't convert tellg output to int

Comment: @StepanYakovenko take a look at this url http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/

Comment: @HadiRasekh please stop using `cplusplus.com` for C++ reference, it's outdated beyond usability. Not only it lacks the newer stuff from C++14, C++17, C++20 and experimental TS, [it also has some considerable errors in some articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com).

Answer (score 1):

> The code snippet below exactly addresses the question in this
>   post :)

```
///
/// Get me my file size in bytes (long long to support any file size supported by your OS.
///
long long Logger::getFileSize()
{
    std::streampos fsize = 0;

    std::ifstream myfile ("myfile.txt", ios::in);  // File is of type const char*

    fsize = myfile.tellg();         // The file pointer is currently at the beginning
    myfile.seekg(0, ios::end);      // Place the file pointer at the end of file

    fsize = myfile.tellg() - fsize;
    myfile.close();

    static_assert(sizeof(fsize) >= sizeof(long long), "Oops.");

    cout << "size is: " << fsize << " bytes.\n";
    return fsize;
}
```