# What is the preferred way to read from a file into a char array?

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, istream, std

Apologies for the basic question; I'm relatively new to C++.

I've looked around and seen many different suggestions for how to read from a file to a char array. For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4373235/1337422) creates a char array of size 10000, but this is suboptimal (either wasted space, or not enough space).

What's the **simplest, and most commonly used** method for reading from a file to a string, or string-like sequence? This is such a common operation; there's got to be a standard way to do it. Is there no one-liner for this?

Comment: There is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring). The answers discuss various methods and their performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use this usually (like when we're **not** reading thousands of files in a loop!):

```
std::ifstream file("data.txt"); 
std::string data {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, 
                  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{} };
```

No need to use `std::copy` (like the other answer; now deleted!).

If you want vector, then use this instead:

```
std::vector<char> data {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, 
                        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{} };
```

However, if you want to populate an existing `std::vector` (or `std::string`), then use `insert` method (both types has `insert` method of same signature!):

```
data.insert(data.end(),                           //insert at end
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, //source begin
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{} );   //source end
```

Hope that helps.